# Storing SQL results as var

Tags: php, sql

I have this code that queries an SQL DB. I want to store the values from the array as variables that I can then PHP echo out elsewhere on the page.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The result just comes as "Array".

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mongolwar");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userdata");

$total = ['player_total'];

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<?php 

echo $total;

;?>
```

I've found the solution:

```
    <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mongolwar");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userdata");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$total = $row[player_total];

}

mysqli_close($con);


?>

<?php 

echo $total;

;?>
```

Comment: "Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?" --- it's easier to say what you're doing right in your code

Comment: `['player_total']` --- what this expression means, how do you think?

Comment: Any pointers on where I can find out how to do this? I've tried searching for how to store values, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: That's the value from SQL I wanted to store. I've tried echo using that expression, which does print the value.

Comment: "That's the value from SQL" --- nope, it's an array with string `'player_total'` in it.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I see, so how would I target the value contained within that array?

Comment: "within that array" --- which "that"?

Comment: Got it...

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mongolwar");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userdata");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$total = $row[player_total];

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Answer (score 1):

In This case your says `$total = ['player_total']`, you probably meant `$total = $result['player_total']`;

Run this code, it will get you close to what you want, then hopefully you can take it the rest of the way:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mongolwar");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userdata");

    mysqli_close($con);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Also, you should really look into prepared statements.